# python: using py installer will not work due to bash "too many arguments"

Tags: python, windows, bash, pyinstaller

I have created a basic python script:

```
from easygui import *
msgbox("helo")
buttonbox("hello",choices=("hello","goodbye"))
print("all done")
```

I then attempted to turn it into a usable file via pyinstaller. I put the following commands into my terminal, with pyinstaller installed, along with easygui.

```
$ cd C:\Users\User\
> pyinstaller --onefile test1.py
```

and then I got the following message:

```
bash: cd: too many arguments
```

anyone know how to fix my problem?

Comment: Have you tried removing the backslash from the end of the line `C:\Users\User\` ? The backslash at the end looks like it is acting as a line-continuation character so both lines end up being interpreted as one command.

Comment: Try: `(cd C:\Users\User\ && pyinstaller --onefile test1.py)`

Comment: both suggestions give me "no such file or directory exists"

Comment: found something that works: pyinstaller filename.py --onefile, if the terminal is opened in the same area. thanks for the help